# Python tkinter accessing object properties

Tags: python, function, properties, tkinter

I am a beginner in python & programming. I am trying to create a template empty windows look a like(sort of!) for my tkinter program.

I have 2 scripts. one is for main program and the other is for all the functions. My idea is to import the script with functions to the main script and use the template.

my main script here(main.py):

```
import module1 as md1
import Tkinter as tk

main_sizex=1280
main_sizey=750
main_posx=1
main_posy=1
main_title="Hello! This is a test"
main_titlesize=22
root=tk.Tk()
md1.Drag_Window(root, main_sizex, main_sizey, main_posx, main_posy, main_title, main_titlesize)
root.mainloop()
```

my other script with functions(module1.py):

```
import Tkinter as tk
def Drag_Window(name,sizex,sizey,posx,posy,title,titlesize):
    def StartMove(event):
        global x,y
        x = event.x
        y = event.y
    def StopMove(event):
        x = None
        y = None
    def OnMotion(event):
        x1 = x
        y1 = y
        x2 = event.x
        y2 = event.y
        deltax = x2-x1
        deltay = y2-y1
        a = name.winfo_x() + deltax
        b = name.winfo_y() + deltay
        name.geometry("+%s+%s" % (a, b))

    name.overrideredirect(True)
    name.config(relief='solid',bd=1,bg='white')
    name.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))
    frame=tk.Frame(name,width=sizex,height=80,relief='solid',bd=1,bg='black')
    frame.place(x=0,y=0)
    frame.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",StartMove)
    frame.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",StopMove)
    frame.bind("<B1-Motion>",OnMotion)
    label=tk.Label(frame,text=title,font=('calibri',(titlesize)),bg='black',fg='white')
    label.place(x=10,y=15)
    button=tk.Button(frame,text='EXIT',font=('calibri',(13)),bg='red',relief='flat',bd=1,width=8,pady=3,command=name.destroy)
    button.place(x=1170,y=20)
    frame2=tk.Frame(name,width=sizex,height=20,relief='solid',bd=1,bg='black')
    frame2.place(x=0,y=sizey-20)
```

My problem is that I need to change some of the properties like `bgcolor` and `text` for some of the label widgets and button widgets in my template . I know that i can add in the additional properties i want to my function like this

```
def Drag_Window(name,sizex,sizey,posx,posy,title,titlesize,propertyA,propertyB,...etc): 
........
........
```

But i am wondering if i can access the widget properties directly from my main script? Is there anyway i can do that?

Something like this:

```
import module1 as md1
import Tkinter as tk

main_sizex=1280
main_sizey=750
main_posx=1
main_posy=1
main_title="Hello! This is a test"
main_titlesize=22
root=tk.Tk()
md1.Drag_Window(root, main_sizex, main_sizey, main_posx, main_posy, main_title, main_titlesize)
md1.button.config(bg='green') # <=
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [class](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

**main.py**

```
import Tkinter as tk

import module1 as md1


main_sizex = 1280
main_sizey = 750
main_posx = 1
main_posy = 1
main_title = "Hello! This is a test"
main_titlesize = 22
root = tk.Tk()
window = md1.Drag_Window(root, main_sizex, main_sizey, main_posx, main_posy, main_title, main_titlesize)
window.button.config(bg='green')
root.mainloop()
```

**module1.py**

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Drag_Window:
    def __init__(self, name, sizex, sizey, posx, posy, title, titlesize):
        self.name = name
        name.overrideredirect(True)
        name.config(relief='solid', bd=1, bg='white')
        name.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex,  sizey,  posx,  posy))
        frame = tk.Frame(name, width=sizex, height=80, relief='solid', bd=1, bg='black')
        frame.place(x=0, y=0)
        frame.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.StartMove)
        frame.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.StopMove)
        frame.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.OnMotion)
        label = tk.Label(frame, text=title, font=('calibri', titlesize), bg='black', fg='white')
        label.place(x=10, y=15)
        self.button = tk.Button(frame, text='EXIT', font=('calibri', 13), bg='red', relief='flat', bd=1, width=8, pady=3, command=name.destroy)
        self.button.place(x=1170, y=20)
        frame2 = tk.Frame(name, width=sizex, height=20, relief='solid', bd=1, bg='black')
        frame2.place(x=0, y=sizey-20)

    def StartMove(self, event):
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y

    def StopMove(self, event):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def OnMotion(self, event):
        x1 = self.x
        y1 = self.y
        x2 = event.x
        y2 = event.y
        deltax = x2 - x1
        deltay = y2 - y1
        a = self.name.winfo_x() + deltax
        b = self.name.winfo_y() + deltay
        self.name.geometry("+%s+%s" % (a, b))
```

Another way (not recommended) - expose widgets as global variable in Drag_Window() function.

```
def Drag_Window(root, ....):
    global button
    ....
    button = Button(....)
```

Comment: BTW, `name` is not good name. Instead use `parent` or `master`.

Comment: WOW! Thanks alot . i didn't expect you to wrote out the whole answer... initially, I was thrown off by the concept of class but after reading your example, it makes some of my doubts clear. one again.. thanks :D